# Setting radio button in ng-repeat loop to $dirty when checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

The issue I have is as follows:

I have X number of radio buttons in an ng-repeat. None of these inputs are checked on first load (View 1). The user then checks one of these inputs then moves to the next view (View 2). When I go back to the previous view (View 1). The input is checked using `ng-checked="{{dealer.selected}}"`.

The problem is that even though the field is 'checked' the validation class is still `ng-pristine`. How can I change it to dirty if pre checked (programmatically )?

Code:

```
                        <td>
                            <div class="selectedDealerInput">
                                <input ng-model="dealerCodeVal.name" id="dealerCode-{{dealer.dealerCode}}" name="dealerCode" value="{{dealer.dealerCode}}" ng-checked="{{dealer.selected}}" type="radio" ng-required="!dealerCodeVal.name">
                                <label for="dealerCode-{{dealer.dealerCode}}">{{dealer.dealerProfile.dealerName}} : {{dealer.selected}}</label>
                                <span data-ng-show="(dealerSelectForm.dealerCode.$dirty || dealerSelectForm.$submitted) && dealerSelectForm.dealerCode.$error.required" class="error">Please select at least one option</span>
                            </div> </td>

                    </tr>
```

Comment: You need to put the html above inside of a <form> element with a name, then replace form with the name of the form created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller use the $setDirty function:

$scope.form.dealerCode.$setDirty();

Comment: I austin, its not working. Cannot read property 'dealerCode' of undefined

Comment: You need to put the html above inside of a <form> element with a name, then replace form with the name of the form created.  $scope.nameOfForm.dealerCode.$setDirty();

Answer (score 0):

From your controller:

```
$scope.form.dealerCode.$dirty = true;
```

Comment: I rrd, its not working. Cannot read property 'dealerCode' of undefined

Comment: s/form/dealerSelectForm